# Pip is uninstalling pytorch built from source when i use 'pip install <some other package that needs pytorch>'. Is there a way?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda, allennlp

I needed to build pytorch from source in order to use the latest cuda toolkit - hence I did that. My environment is a conda enviornment.

The package I am trying to install is **allennlp**.

`Pip list` is not showing **torch** installed, conda is showing it is.
Tried building allennlp from source through:

```
conda skeleton pypi <package>
conda build <package>
```

**conda build** is also causing problems due to incompability with pip packages etc...

I am just wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

**For example:** Tell pip that torch is already installed so it stops uninstalling the current torch (why can't it just pick it up as installed).
Appreciate the help!

Comment: if pip is trying to uninstall torch, then it must know that it was installed.... My guess is that the requirement in allennlp `torch<1.8.0,>=1.6.0` is causing the uninstallation

Comment: I removed the version dependency but still the same result. Dirk's answer worked for me. I still dont know how pip can uninstall but not consider it as an already installed package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `allennlp` with `pip install --no-deps allennlp`, but then you have to make sure the other dependencies are there yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. And then i manually installed rest of the dependencies, and had a couple of code patches also that needed to be done.